# Block hotlinking but whitelist certain pages / search engines

Tags: apache, .htaccess, search-engine, http-referer

What I'm doing right now is to block hotlinking of any images in a certain folder and redirecting to the website containing that image:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?mydomain.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)\.(gif|jpg|png)$ /$1.html [R,L]
```

What I want to do now is to whitelist certain pages

e.g. bing.com | google.com | google.fr | google.de | etc.

I guess that's quite an easy task but I'm terrible with .htaccess :/

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?mydomain.com/.*$ [NC]
# add whatever other search engines you want to whitelist
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !(bing.com|google|yahoo) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)\.(gif|jpg|png)$ /$1.html [R,L]
```

Comment: doesn't seem to whitelist them